# How to get an object from a list of objects in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have the following list of objects variable:

```
variable "objects" {
  type = "list"
  description = "list of objects
  default = [
      {
        id = "name1"
        attribute = "a"
      },
      {
        id = "name2"
        attribute = "a,b"
      },
      {
        id = "name3"
        attribute = "d"
      }
  ]
}
```

How do I get element with id = "name2" ?

Comment: You'd need to iterate over every object and inspect it to do so which is not something Terraform can really do. Can you provide more context in what you're trying to achieve or explain why your data structure needs to be like that?

Comment: This is clearly exposing my lack of knowledge with terraform. Anyways, I am trying to pass a definition of a list of objects into a module. This module will then invoke another module by passing in only a specific object from the list e.g "name2". Bad idea?

Comment: That sounds like it might be overly complicated. Can you more clearly explain what you're trying to directly achieve (eg create some EC2 instances with some specific config) and list any constraints you have for whatever reason?

Comment: Many constraints. First of all, I am using the vsphere provider and I am creating an environment that consists of  virtual machines via https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/d/virtual_machine.html resource. Further constrained in the sense that each vm needs to be provided with a specific ip and hostname, network. I was looking at only having a list of that being passed to a module that would then hide all the other intricacies of the virtual machine resource and encapsulating that in a module for reuse elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking to create a set of `vsphere_virtual_machine` [resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html) from a list of IPs and hostnames, I might try this:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count = "${length(var.virtual_machine_ips)}"

  // the rest of your virtual machine config
  // such as template ID, CPUs, memory, disks...

  vapp {
    properties {
      // your vApp properties may vary based on what your template actually is.
      // these examples are for the CoreOS template.

      "guestinfo.hostname" = "${index(var.virtual_machine_hostnames, count.index)}"
      "guestinfo.interface.0.ip.0.address" = "${index(var.virtual_machine_ips, count.index)}"
    }
  }
}
```

(This is assuming that you are setting IP and hostname via [vApp config](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#cloning-from-an-ovf-ova-created-template-with-vapp-properties); if not then it may look similar but put the hostname and IP addresses somewhere outside the `vsphere_virtual_machine.vapp.properties` block.)

Where the `terraform.tfvars` file might look like this:

```
virtual_machine_ips = ["10.0.2.2", "10.0.2.3", "10.0.2.4"]
virtual_machine_hostnames = ["banana", "pineapple", "coconut"]
```

This is a simpler and more idiomatic way of accomplishing what you're trying to do, since working with complex objects in Terraform interpolation syntax is not easy.

Comment: Thank you, we are not using vApp config but your comment about trying to avoid complex objects is noted until next release of terraform perhaps? In the meantime, I will probably pass in simple corresponding lists like you suggested above or pass in each object map as a variable instead of a list of them.

Answer (score 64):

You get the map with id="name2" with the following expression:

```
var.objects[index(var.objects.*.id, "name2")]
```

For a quick test, run the following one-liner in terraform console:

```
[{id = "name1", attribute = "a"}, {id = "name2", attribute = "a,b"}, {id = "name3", attribute = "d"}][index([{id = "name1", attribute = "a"}, {id = "name2", attribute = "a,b"}, {id = "name3", attribute = "d"}].*.id, "name2")]
```

Comment: i think this should be the answer; the splat in `var.objects.*.id` is useful, thanks!

Comment: What is "index" in the above code examples?

Comment: @G.Stoynev That's a pre-defined function from terraform: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/index_function

Answer (score 11):

You can't nested multiple levels of square brackets to get n levels inside a data structure. However you can use the interpolation functions to retrieve such values. In this case you'll want to use the lookup function to retrieve the value from the map which itself has been accessed with square brackets, that will look like this...

```
${lookup(var.objects[1], "id")}
```

Rowan is correct, complex data structures are difficult to work with in current versions of Terraform. However it looks like it won't be too long before we can expect better support in this area. The upcoming version 0.12 will include [rich types](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-rich-value-types) adding improvements to lists and maps.

Comment: thanks, so in 0.12 we should be able to do something like `var.objects[1].id` ?

Comment: seems not work in 0.11, if you run with objects inside a list? https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18322

Comment: Sorry, I confirm this could work in Terraform v0.11.13 in macOS: `${lookup(var.vms[count.index], "folder_type")}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated way if you're only working with pairs.

```
variable "objects" {
  type = list
  description = "list of objects"
  default = [
      {
        id = "name1"
        attribute = "a"
      },
      {
        id = "name2"
        attribute = "a,b"
      },
      {
        id = "name3"
        attribute = "d"
      }
  ]
}

locals {

  massaged-objects = {
    for object in var.objects:
      object.id => object.attribute
  }

}

output example {

  value = local.massaged-objects["name2"]

}
```