# Terraform: How to select a value from a nested list of maps within a list?

Tags: azure, terraform

So in the following I have subnets which is a list of maps within the main vnets list. IF I am creating a subnet resource for azure, how do I go about extracting the subnet names for each resource? And if I were to go a level deeper, how would I extract the SG names?

```js
variable "vnets" {
  default = [
    {
      vnet_name     = "test-vnet"
      address_space = "10.250.0.0"
      network_size  = 16
      subnets = [
        {
          name                     = "first-subnet"
          network_security_group   = "first-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "first-sg"
              priority                   = 100
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name                     = "second-subnet"
          network_security_group   = "second-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "second-sg"
              priority                   = 100
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what did you try so far? Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119400/how-to-get-an-object-from-a-list-of-objects-in-terraform?

Comment: yea have read that, but that doesn't help with trying to read values from a nested list of maps. Its currently a blocker for me trying anything beyond list of maps, i know that works with the count variable and then lookup. But as soon as I add nested list of maps, i am not even sure where to start. Do I set the count to var.vnets or var.vnets.subnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `locals` to get subnet names and security group names:

```
locals {

   subnet_names = flatten(var.vnets[*].subnets[*].name)
   
   subnet_names_with_vnet_name = { 
         for vnet in var.vnets[*]:
           (vnet.vnet_name) =>  vnet.subnets[*].name
   }
   
   security_group_names = flatten(var.vnets[*].subnets[*].security_group_rules[*].name)

}

output "subnet_names" {
  value = local.subnet_names
}

output "subnet_names_with_vnet_name" {
  value = local.subnet_names_with_vnet_name
}

output "security_group_names" {
  value = local.security_group_names
}
```

which results in:

```
security_group_names = [
  "first-sg",
  "second-sg",
]
subnet_names = [
  "first-subnet",
  "second-subnet",
]
subnet_names_with_vnet_name = {
  "test-vnet" = [
    "first-subnet",
    "second-subnet",
  ]
}
```

Comment: would I put this "locals" inside the resource block or outside?

Comment: @shan You put it outside. It is its own block, like `variable` block.

Comment: what is the vnet.vnet refer to? currently throws an error for me saying object does not have attribute

Comment: @shan Should be `vnet.vnet_name`. Sorry.